# Editing First Element in List within Tuple in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I'm new to Haskell, so bear with me.

Is it possible to remove the first element of a list within a tuple?

So if we have something like:

```
function:: [([x], y)] -> [([x], y)]
```

Could we edit the list so that the first element of the list gets deleted? So that tuples like:

```
[([1,2,3], 4), ([5,6,7], 8), ([9,10,11,12], 13), ([14,15], 16)]
```

become

```
[([2,3], 4), ([6,7], 8), ([10,11,12], 13), ([15], 16)]
```

?

Or is this not possible and am I wasting my time trying to figure this out?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Your type signature itself indicates that such     
thing is possible.

Comment: How would you approach this then?

Answer (score 1):

Start by writing the simpler function `([x],y) -> ([x],y)`. Something like this would work:

```
f ((x:xs), y) = (xs, y)
```

You'll need to decide what to do when the list is empty. One option is to return the empty list again:

```
f ([], y) = ([], y)
```

The other alternative is to produce an error as the `tail` function does in which case you could just use that for your entire implementation.

```
f (xs, y) = (tail xs, y)
```

Next you can use the higher order function called `map` to get your final function. It's type is `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]`. If you pass `f` as the first argument then `a` and `b` are both `([x],y)`.